# I am unable to load a page with ec2 instance ip address

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-ec2, ip

I have tried to connect a page which is hosted in ec2 instance. It is showing server timed out error but rest of my collegues able to connect to  it.

I use **mac** laptop

Things i did:

1. clearing cache
2. tried to change my network
   3.tried in incognito mode

nothing works. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more details?

Comment: @Rostyslav i have hosted a web application in ec2 instance. when i tried loading the page its not connecting . i get server timed out error but my collegues able to load the page

Comment: How did you host it? Whar HTTP server is EC2 behind proxy...? You provide no details

Answer (score 1):

Things to normally check:

- Confirm that the EC2 instance is **running a web server** (try to access it from somewhere else, or login to the instance and try `curl localhost`)
- Confirm that the EC2 instance is in a **public subnet** (defined as the subnet having a Route Table entry that points to an Internet Gateway)
- Confirm that the **Security Group associated with the EC2 instance** is permitting inbound access on port 80 (for HTTP) and possibly port 443 (for HTTPS)
- Confirm that you are attempting to **access the instance via a public IP address** (not a private IP address) and that the public IP address is currently associated with the instance
- Don't change default NACL rules

You mention "rest of my colleagues able to connect" but you don't mention from *where* they are accessing the instance. Quite clearly, something is either different with your computer or with the network that you are using. I would suggest you focus on:

- The **Security Group "inbound" rules**, to confirm that they are not blocking access
- **Try to connect from a different network** (eg home vs office vs tethered via your phone) to confirm that your network is not blocking access

If you are connecting from the **same network as your colleagues**, then the problem is on your computer. This is unlikely because the timeout normally indicates a lack of network connectivity (rather than software configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Checking the security group, the inbound rules was by the launch wizard created by AWS. It had only port 22 enabled for SSH.
Adding a rule for type HTTP and port 80 should resolve the issue.